# How to use regular expression to match whole String

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val it = ("\\b" + "'as" + "\\b").r.findAllMatchIn("'as you are a's".toLowerCase());
      val lst = it.map(_.start).toList
      print(lst)
}
```

I expected the answer would be `List(0)` (because it matched `'as` and index should be `0`), but it gave me `List()`

Also,

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val it = ("\\b" + "as" + "\\b").r.findAllMatchIn("'as you are a's".toLowerCase());
      val lst = it.map(_.start).toList
      print(lst)
  }
```

This gave me the answer `List(1)` but I expected the answer to be `List()` because I want to match the whole thing (need exactly match `'as` ), that is why I use `\b` here

But this worked well:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val it = ("\\b" + "a's" + "\\b").r.findAllMatchIn("'as you are a's".toLowerCase());
      val lst = it.map(_.start).toList
      print(lst)
  }
```

it returned `List(12)` which is what I want (because it matched `a's` and index should be `12`).

I did not understand why it did not work when I put `'` at the front of word. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `\b` does not match if the first character after that is not a letter or other word character. So it will not match when it is followed by a `'`. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Edit:

```
val it = ("(?:\\b|')" + "as" + "\\b").r.findAllMatchIn("'as you are a's".toLowerCase())
```

Comment: @yeah, so how I match the whole String?

Comment: You were not expected to match the whole String anyway... Only the `'as` if possible. Remove the `\\b` from the front.